# can I assign HTML page into Global variable to download it as PDF?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using Code Igniter framework, and tcpdf third-parties

I have a global variable in controller :

```
     public $pdf_content = '';
```

here is some of my function to book :

```
     $data['success'] = $this->hotel_model->set_hotel(); //get the data from database
            //view reservation detail
            $this->load->view('hotel/header');
            $this->load->view('hotel/success', $data );
            $this->load->view('hotel/footer');

            //assign the HTML page into global variable
            $this->pdf_content =  $this->load->view('hotel/success', $data , TRUE);
```

In my view file I'm using a button to download the HTML as pdf file, here is the download function :

```
public function download(){
    $this->load->library("Pdf");
    $this->load->helper('pdf_helper');

    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

            // Add a page
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $this->pdf_content , 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
            $pdf->Output('invoice.pdf', 'I');
}
```

Both function located inside the same controller.

I think there is nothing wrong in my code based on any tutorial I ever read.

But it downloaded some blank page instead, and when I try to assign string value into $pdf_content, it works fine, The string value is written into the downloaded PDF file.

Anybody know what I missed there? 
Or there is something wrong in my code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The download function is being called from html after the //view reservation detail is being rendered ?

Comment: @carlos delgado : correct, I'm using button in the view file that refer to the download function ...... thx for the reply btw.

Comment: But the content of the $this->pdf_content is being assigned while you return a view. And if you call download method from a button in html, then the variable will be empty (try changing : public $pdf_content = ''; to public $pdf_content = 'This content should be printed'; )._. you need to assign it in the same moment when you execute $pdf->Output()

Comment: ummm, I don't quite get it... if I assign string into $pdf_content, of course it would be printed.

Comment: Yes, but when are you executing the first block of code ? First is executed that block, then a html view is returned to the browser. and then you call the download function ? If it's so, it doesn't sense at all because the value will be always empty. If it's not, could you explain more in your question what's the order in which the things are getting executed ?

Comment: ah, so it was my wrong method that assigned a null value...do you have any other idea how to assign the html page into controller variable? .........because if I merge both function into one it resulted in another error but printed the html page into downloaded pdf correctly.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways. The easiest would be to save the page as pdf manually (ctrl+p) and then make it available as download. OR, you can show the page and run the following script in the bottom of the body.

```
    <script>
           var yourName = "someName';
            document.title = yourName;
            window.print();
</script>
```

This fires the ctrl+p command and allows users to either print or save the page.

Comment: hi dwarf, thx for the reply, but I'm looking for more convenient way :)

Comment: Does your code actually assign the page to the variable or throws it the exception before that?

Comment: yup, I assign the page into $pdf_content as written in my code up there.

Comment: I see but did you test it? because if that works the error is between the variable and the file downloading. Because like you said, if you insert a string it would be fine. However if this line does not actually return the code of the page you are assigning a null-value.       $this->load->view('hotel/success', $data , TRUE);

Comment: Hi again dwarf... when I merge both function as one, it works fine, the HTML page is written in the downloaded PDF file too...... so as far as I know,  the $pdf_content contain the HTML page as it value.